# Redirect if an object is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chargify

I am using the `chargify_api_ares` gem to search for a Chargify Subscription.

```
@current_subscription = Chargify::Subscription.find_by_customer_reference(@dealer.id)
redirect_to(dealers_path) unless @current_subscription
```

However, if no subscription is found it never makes it to the next line where it redirects because `find_by_customer_reference` spits out a 404 if it doesn't find anything, but I'd like some way for it to return `nil` instead so I can make it to the next line where I redirect the user out of there.

Does anyone know how I can make fail softly or a better way I can redirect the user if no object is found? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the method is raising an [`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html) exception, which you can catch and turn into a redirection:

```
begin
  @current_subscription = Chargify::Subscription.find_by_customer_reference(@dealer.id)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to dealers_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I actually had to `rescue ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound` but yea. Thanks.